# remove duplicate messages from kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm exporting data from a database into Kafka by sending the data in fixed sized batches. I just resend the whole batch, if there is a failure in one batch. My idea was rather than figuring out which messages got imported correctly to deal with the fact that some messages are imported twice.

Kafka implements this compaction step where from all messages with the same message key only the newest message is kept. The compaction would remove all duplicate messages since all the messages have a unique key.

Is there a way to only read from a Kafka topic up to the point where the compaction is complete? It's okay if I can't always read up until the most recent messages as long as I don't read any messages twice.

Comment: how did you do solve it? I have got the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't force Kafka compaction, so the only option is to wait until compaction occures (and it could be very tricky).

I think the much better way to handle this situation is to make your consumer idempotent - an idempotent consumer doesn't care how much duplicates you have in your stream, the result remains the same.